# EM_SETSEL not working in .docx (word document)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working on a simple program that sends WM_COPY to an open .docx file (word document). I tested my code on other applications and it seems to work all fine. But whenever I try to use my code on an open word document, it returns false at `SendMessage(hwndChild, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1)`.

I have tried a couple things:

- Use code on notepad (not richtext) and stickynotes (richttext) and it works perfectly with the code beneath.
- Remove the line `SendMessage(hwndChild, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1)` and then manual highlight the text in the word document and run program. It succeeds and copies the content to clipboard with help of WM_COPY.

Does anyone know why `EM_SETSEL` is not working in a word document?

```
int main() {
    HWND app = FindWindowEx(0, 0, "OpusApp", 0); 
    EnumChildWindows(app, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM) NULL);

    return 0;
}


BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam) {
    uint8_t max_path_length = 255;
    char *str = new char[max_path_length];
    memset(str, 0, max_path_length);
    GetClassName(hwndChild, str, max_path_length);

    /// Execute when edit handle is obtained
    if(strcmpi(str, "_WwG") == 0) {
        if(SendMessage(hwndChild, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1)) {
            SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
        } else {
            MessageBox(0, "Can't select all!", "Report", MB_OK);
        }
    }

    str = NULL;
    delete [] str;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`EM_SETSEL` only works for an Edit control. I doubt that Word uses the standard control.